# Modifying meta keys in User Meta Pro using user_meta_pre_user_register not working

Tags: plugins, user-meta

When a user registers I need to modify the information before it is written to the database.

I’m using the `user_meta_pre_user_register` function to do some maths to change a value from stone and pounds to kg. In my app I’m always storing weight in kg and converting it to and from stone if required.

If I print the `$userData` array when the user registers it is displaying what I expect, a number converted from stone to kg (e.g. `[weight] => 65.77086`) but it’s not writing this value to the database. All the unmodified values are being written correctly.

Am I using the correct function and is there anything I’m missing?

```
add_filter( 'user_meta_pre_user_register', 'user_meta_pre_user_register_function' );
function user_meta_pre_user_register_function( $userData ){

    //If the weights units conditional is set kg save the value to 'weight'
    //If the weights units conditional is set stone, convert value to kg then save to 'weight'

    if($userData['weight_units'] == 'kg'){
    $userData['weight'] = $userData['weight_kg'];
    }else{
    $userData['weight'] = stone_to_kg($userData['weight_st'], $userData['weight_lbs']);
    }

    print_r($userData); //This is showing what I expect

    return $userData;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the Db configuration that doesn't support the float numbers/precision  (in case it doesn't use the `wp_postmeta`). Could you show as the print_r of 2 examples to make a comparison ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the array: `Array ( [first_name] => David [height] => 180 [height_units] => Centimetres [weight] => 65.77086 [weight_st] => 10 [weight_lbs] => 5 [weight_units] => Stone [waist_circumference] => 32 [waist_circumference_units] => Inches [dob_date] => 12 [dob_month] => 12 [dob_year] => 1212 [postcode] => LS6 123 [location_if_not_in_uk] => GB [user_email] => 12@test.com [user_pass] => xxxxxx [i_have_read_and_agree_to_the_terms_and_conditions] => I have read and agree to the terms and conditions )`

Comment: Does the User Meta Pro use a custom table? If yes can you send the create to see the type?

Comment: It just uses `wp_usermeta`

Comment: Is there any overriding filter? That maybe messed up the changes you made?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, in the functions file or in the plugin files?

Comment: Reading the Doc for the plugin it should update as you expected. But I don't have access to the actual code base. For that reason I suspect something overriding your `$userData` data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. From trying to debug the plugin it seems that the it's some how reverting to original array in the `UserInsert.php` file, but it's a bit beyond me to work out where.

Comment: I would probably start debugging the filter to the UserInsert.php and going backward will see where the changes occur. As this is a premium plugin I can request access to the code so better contact the plugin developers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing the plugin files. Not ideal, but when the plugin author ignores your emails and forum posts it's what I had to do (I have paid for the pro version...).

In the rare case that this may help someone else, in `UserInsert.php` I added the filter

```
$userData = apply_filters('user_meta_pre_user_register', $userData);
```

before

```
$this->userData = $userData;        
$this->setMetaData();
```

as I realised that when the data was being sent to `setMetaData()` it was too soon and hadn't reached the filter so didn't have the extra meta fields added.

Why this is happening in this plugin, I have no idea....